Copies of the same Prefab instance all interact at the same time when collided with. How to separate these interactions?
I'm developing a game in Unity for a class and have hit a huge roadblock for its development.
I'm using the same prefab of a chalice as a central collectible for the game and coded it to disappear when collided with and add to a total point counter. In this initial version, there are only 3 separate chalices that have unique objectives but share the same interact that if they collide with the player they disappear. Similarly, there is a portion where there is an array of fake chalices with the real one hidden amongst them that will respawn the player if you pick the wrong one.
However, whenever I interact with any of the chalices it triggers the same response for all of them. I've tweaked it enough such that the disappear code doesn't affect the fake chalices, but the respawn code affects all of them still.
The codes themselves are applied to the player character "Toy_Robot", and acts as the primary catalyst for these interacts.
My code is very simple, but any of the more complicated solutions I used only broke the game further, so here's the code for the object disappearance:
public class ObjectDestruction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Chalice;
    public GameObject Chalice1;
    public GameObject Chalice2;
    public GameObject Chalice3;

    void Start()
    {
        Chalice1 = GameObject.Find("Tutorial Chalice");
        Chalice2 = GameObject.Find("Hidden Chalice");
        Chalice3 = GameObject.Find("Climb Chalice");
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Toy_Robot)
    {
        //Chalice.gameObject.SetActive(false); //The original remover

        if (Chalice1) 
        {
            Chalice1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Chalice2) 
        {
            Chalice2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Chalice3) 
        {
            Chalice3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}

And here's the code for player respawn:
public class WrongChalice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Spawn;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject Fake_Chalices;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Toy_Robot)
    {
        if (Fake_Chalices.gameObject)
        {
            player.transform.position = Spawn.position;
        }
    }
}

In the unity engine itself, I'm specifically applying the unique instances I made in the indicated slots, but this only proved to work in separating the fake chalices from being removed when interacted with. Furthermore, while the chalices I do want to disappear are separate from each other and the original prefab, I haven't significantly changed them from their base prefab and if this is a significant detail, it would be nice to know. The Toy_Robot variable is a separate public variable that has its own code and prefab outside of the chalices and is the player object.
Any advice would help.

You never use the variable you are calling Toy_Robot - how do you expect the game to recognize anything about it?

Does this answer your question? Differentiating between player and other objects colliders during collision detection

Mostly, you should re-examine what an if statement like if (Chalice1) is actually doing - you seem to think it is comparing the value/reference to something else, but that's not what is happening. The == operator and the Toy_Robot variable should probably make an appearance inside the if statement, for starters.

The problem isn't that I can't differentiate player and object colliders, it's that the colliders for all of the chalices interact at the same time despite only one being impacted.

im going to go out on a limb and guess that the ObjectDestruction is attached to the player. (The question does not include a [mre] so it truly is just a guess).  If that's the case, then when the player's collider enters any trigger, every statement in OnTriggerEnter runs because all of the if statements resolve to true. If I'm guessing wrong then please edit the question to include a [mre]. On the other hand, if I'm guessing right, then an answer that instructs on how to distinguish objects would be helpful.

My only major issue with the distinguish object answer is that I don't understand how it would help allow individual interacts between prefabs, and therefore to differentiate between chalices for both codes.

in ObjectDestruction try void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {other.gameObject.SetActive(false);} and then in WrongChalice you would want to include something to distinguish between the chalices.  But even in ObjectDestruction you may want to distinguish between chalices vs other kinds of triggers the player might run into - not every trigger involves destruction when it's touched, perhaps.
